# Can't upload files - Nothing transferring to $_FILES variable AT ALL

Tags: php, forms

Ok so I've tried everything I can think of and cannot get the file upload to work.

- PHP File Upload is ON
- PHP Max upload size is set to 1024M
- I've tried setting the max size in the Form to all sorts of things
- Form HTML contains the correct stuff

I've now cut down the PHP to a simple script to show me what it's seeing in an attempt to troubleshoot this. There is literally no other PHP script running on the page the Form "action" goes to.

Regardless of whether or not I submit the Form to get to the PHP script, or point the browser straight there to eliminate a possible issue on the Form, the $_FILES array is completely void of data, NOTHING at all.

Note that I'v put some other data in the Form to verify $_POST is working.

I give up... What is going on here???

**Minimized version of the Form:**

```
<form id="create_form" method="post" action="...bla.php" encytype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4096000">
<input name="file" type="file" class="form-control"></input>
```

**COMPLETE PHP Script:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$invoice = $_POST['id'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$property = $_POST['property'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];

echo 'Invoice: '.$invoice.'<br />';
echo 'Date: '.$date.'<br />';
echo 'Amount: $'.$amount.'<br />';
echo 'Type: '.$type.'<br />';
echo 'Property: '.$property.'<br />';
echo 'File Name: '.$fileName.'<br />';
echo 'File Size: '.$fileSize.'<br />';
echo 'File Error: '.$fileError.'<br />';
echo '$_FILES Array: </br >';
print_r ($_FILES);
?>
```

**Which Outputs...**

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in ...bla.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: file in ...bla.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: file in ...bla.php on line 13 
Invoice: 411 
Date: 2017-06-14 
Amount: $65 
Type: electric 
Property: 774 
File Name:  
File Size:  
File Error:  
$_FILES Array:  
Array ( )
```

Comment: Is that PHP in the same script as the HTML? Or is that PHP script executed at any time without form data being submitted? Because if so, the errors are only being generated on the first load of the page / when the script is loaded without the data.

Comment: The PHP is a separate file. I'm not concerned about the Notices though, because as soon as I get the $_FILES data to fill in, they won't be there. I just had error reporting on just in case I missed something lol. The copied bit here is WITH the Form submitted to it though - and all the $_POST data worked unlike the $_FILES data.

Comment: what's `encytype` ? Is it a question typo or a code typo?

Comment: You've got to be kidding... THAT WAS IT! Code typo... best part is I copied and pasted that snippet from somewhere just to be sure it was right lol Must have overlooked that 100 times... Sometimes another pair of eyes is priceless haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's `encytype` ? Is it a question typo or a code typo?

Thanks to apokryfos - that was it! Overlooked 100 times...

The corrected code:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```